# Transforming a equivalence relationship with divided case

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am transforming an equivalence relationship: $A = $B.

It is given that $B$ has different cases under different condition:

- if $C$, then $B$=$B1$
- if $\neg C$,then $B$=$B2$

(where $C$ is a Boolean expression)

Question: which of below is the correct way to transform the original equivalence: $A = $B:

1. $ (C \land ( A = B1)) \lor (\neg C \land ( A = B2)) $
2. $ (C \implies (A = B1))\lor (\neg C \implies ( A = B2)) $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 is correct.

The most straightforward way to translate your condition looks like 2, but with $\land$ instead of $\lor$: $$(C\Rightarrow (A = B_1))\land (\lnot C\Rightarrow (A = B_2)).$$ 
This condition is equivalent to 1: $$(C\land (A = B_1))\lor (\lnot C\land (A = B_2))$$

To see this algebraically, translate $C\Rightarrow (A = B_1)$ to $\lnot C \lor (A = B_1)$, and similarly for $\lnot C\Rightarrow (A = B_2)$, apply the distributive law, and eliminate the false expressions $C\land \lnot C$ and $(A = B_1)\land (A = B_2)$ from the disjunction.

Comment: Initially I also thought 1 is correct. Actually I encounter this question when proving an example from a book. I found that only use 2 will pass. Here is the example (red arrow shows the problematic step): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NIs4wTP5Ebn39P4JZX_EacrQ83GJuNAC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can I ask why 2 should be modified to use $\land$ instead of $\lor$? It is intuitive to think that only one of the condition can be true at any time, which translate to $\lor$. If we use $\land$, it seems that we are requiring all the conditions to be satisfied at the same time.

Comment: 1. I don't see the connection between the example in your book and this question. The step marked with the red arrow seems to be of a different form entirely. 2. We have that if C is true, then A = B1. **And** we also have that if C is false, then A = B2. Both conditionals are true, so their conjunction is true.

Comment: If you said "or" instead, you'd only be requiring one conditional or the other  to be true.

Comment: @modeller By using $\land$ you are saying that both *conditionals* are true. That is different from both *conditions* being true.

Comment: @AlexKruckman About the book example, the Notation (N j: 0<=j < i+1: b[j] > 0) represents the number of elements greater than 0 in the domain of [0, i]. Its relation to this question is that we need to convert the notation in step 2 to step 3 (red arrow points to) where notation is changed to (N j: 0<=j < i: b[j]). This conversion involves in a conditional form: if b[i] > 0, then (N j: 0<=j < i+1: b[j] > 0) = ( j: 0<=j < i: b[j]) + 1; if b[i] <=0, then  (N j: 0<=j < i+1: b[j] > 0) = (N j: 0<=j < i: b[j])

Comment: @AlexKruckman I need to check the difference between conditionals being true and condition being true. Let me do some reading and try your modified version first.

Comment: @Bram28 I probably need more reading about these notations: conditionals, implications, guarded statement. (They seems related). Any good material about understanding the nature of implication relationship? Appreciate it.

Comment: Got it all worked out. Thank you.

Comment: @Bram28 is there any difference between "conditional" and "implication"?

Comment: @AlexKruckman New relevant question: If the two ways are equivalent, in the case of only one conditional: If M, then N, I shall get M => N = M ^ N. But I could not prove it. Where did it go wrong?